# Azure trying to Start VM with Tasks(preview), receive InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant Error

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Whenever I try to create a Task in the Microsoft Azure Tasks(preview) to start a Virtual Machine, I am able to create the task, however the task fails to execute with a InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant Error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant",
    "message": "The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/tokennumbers/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/tokennumbers/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/tokennumbers' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later."
  }
}
```

I have tried just running it in the Logic Apps Designer but it returns error 401.

Answer (score 0):

> The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/tokennumbers/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/tokennumbers/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/tokennumbers' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later."   }

The above error states the tenant on which the account you logged in does not include in the subscription.

I followed this [Document](https://github.com/fabioharams/stopstart-logicapps)  to create a stop/start the virtual machine using the Logic app.

**Designer:**

I created the same designer using the document to make sure when creating the connection giving the correct tenant.

[image]

Also, check that the subscription, resource group, and Virtual machine name are correct.

[image]

I was given 15 minutes delay to start the virtual machine.

[image]

The logic app was executed and started the virtual machine successfully.

**Portal:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found that if I follow the below video to use the VM Task (Preview) auto-generate the Logic App, the Authentication will be in trouble by default!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/it-ops-talk/auto-shutdown-and-auto-start-an-azure-vm

I follow the below steps can solve the problem.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/405123/azure-logic-app-azure-vm-connector-invalidauthenti

To make it easier, the Marketplace also has "Start/Stop VMs during off-hours (V2)" can save some of my troubles.  I follow the steps in this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjM0N6N12NA

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. **Can you [edit] your answer to summarize the relevant guidance from the link?** Answers on Stack Overflow can certainly link to additional information, but they should stand on their own even if the page they are linking to is later (re)moved. This is important because often, over time, the linked pages are no longer available, which is frustrating for future members of the community.